# Is there a meaning in a name marked on the rear of a headstone rather than the front?

Tags: social-history, catholic-church, everyday-life, historical-research

I have found a family headstone with the names of the deceased on the front (with many details), and a military cross (for their son) in front of the stone.  On the rear of the stone is a name and age, but no years.  If the person on the rear is who I believe it to be, they would have pre-deceased their parents (who are on the front of the stone) by many years.  I wonder if there is some significance to carving a name in the rear rather than the front?

Comment: Where is the grave located?  I've seen a few gravestones with later burials recorded on the back of the stone in the UK and Ireland, but not earlier ones.  Also, this question might be a better fit for [Genealogy & Family History:SE](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I will post it there as well (found it later).  The stone is in Canada, though the occupants are Irish.

Comment: I'm guessing the person may not be buried in that grave, but just a guess

Comment: @CLovell If you've posted elsewhere, please delete this question. Having two copies of it fragments answers and means people can waste their time answering questions that have already been dealt with somewhere else.

Comment: Standard government headstones at Arlington National Cemetery sometimes show the veteran's name on the front and, where the spouse is interred in the same plot, the spouse's name on the reverse.  For my parents, for example, the headstone has my father, deceased 2005, on the front and my mother, deceased 1996, on the reverse - they are buried in the same plot.  On the other hand, my mother's sister, deceased 1998, has her own government headstone on a plot next to her husband, deceased 1955.  So could be a simple as who is in what plot.